# Why does XCode prefix controller with xxxViewController instead of xxxController?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I don't understand : in all tutorials on iOS, it shows a classical 3 parts Model, View, Controller, then why does XCode prefix controller with xxxViewController instead of xxxController ?

This makes believe that the controller is just for the View and not for the Model and so close to MVVM than classic MVC.

In answers given it says it's not MVC.

But if I look at standford University course it clearly depicts iOS development as classical MVC in Lecture1.pdf @ http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/cgi-bin/drupal/downloads-2010-fall

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Xcode doesn't do this for all controllers, Just for view controllers (which are subclasses of UIViewController). It makes it easier to find which ones manage views, You can create other controllers and name them what you like.

Comment: Yes but my question is rather : is it also the control of the associated model ?

Comment: Considering that a controller mediates between the model and the view, as the diagram in your question shows - yes. The naming is just a convenience that you'll see the benefit of if you write an app that has a lot of views.

Answer (score 0):

As g_wolfman comments in [this Apple discussion thread](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2681126?start=0&tstart=0):

> Despite Apple's use of the term MVC in their developer documentation,
>   they don't actually use it; they use a variant of
>   [Presentation-Abstraction-Control
>   (PAC)|http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presentation-abstraction-control].
>
> The key difference is that in MVC, the view gets information directly
>   from the model and the controller is only concerned with changing the
>   model. Hence the view may need to know how to transform data from the
>   model as part of creating the view. In PAC, the view and the model are
>   completely isolated from each other; everything passes through the
>   controller. This allows the view to be written in such a way as to
>   avoid needing any "business logic".

EDIT - --
from apple doc - http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaDesignPatterns/CocoaDesignPatterns.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH6-SW1

> Combining Roles
>
> One can merge the MVC roles played by an object, making an object, for
>   example, fulfill both the controller and view roles—in which case, it
>   would be called a view controller. In the same way, you can also have
>   model-controller objects. For some applications, combining roles like
>   this is an acceptable design.

Comment: and also as stated above my Abizern..its up to you what name you wish to have...u can name any controller without prefixing view.

Comment: But in Standford University course they clearly stated it's MVC see my update.

Comment: refer apple doc before downvotoing - http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MVC.html

Comment: In Apple doc it's clearly MVC. Contrary to windows phone mvvm there is explicitely controller.

Comment: Again, if you copy language from another person, you must provide proper citation or you are merely stealing credit from others. I've edited your answer to do this, but you need to do this yourself in the future.